# I'm making a "parallax" effect but it doesn't work

Tags: html, css, image, parallax

I'm kinda new to `HTML` and `CSS` and am building a website, but I don't seem to be abled to create a parallex effect on my image... **The image is just not showing.** Can you see what's wrong with my (simplyfied) code?

```css
.parallax {
  background-image: url("images/start-background.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parallax"></div>
  <h1 class="title-home">This is my title</h1>
  <h2 class="subtitle-home">This is my subtitle. Example, example, etc.</h2>
  <div class="parallax"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check the console. Probably the wrong path. Parallax requires JavaScript as well.

Comment: @Phix The image not showing could be a path issue, but parallax does not require JS. There are css only solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a `min-height`.I made 500px here but you can change.

```css
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/binaries/content/gallery/metofficegovuk/hero-images/weather/cloud/cumulus-cloud.jpg");
  min-height: 500px; 
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parallax"></div>
  <h1 class="title-home">This is my title</h1>
  <h2 class="subtitle-home">This is my subtitle. Example, example, etc.</h2>
  <div class="parallax"></div>
</body>

</html>
```